# How to generate a CSV file in action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, action

I am trying to generate a CSV output with data from my database. I would like to provide these data to a third party, so I picture I would give to someone a URL (`website.com/api_data/cars`) and by accessing this URL the person would be able to work with it - I think I want to access the URL and then to see there (in the action) data displayed and separated by `,` or `;`.

But how to do that?

So far, I am trying following approach:

```
csv_string = CSV.generate do |csv|
  cols = ["column one", "column two", "column three"]
  csv << cols
  csv << ["A", "B", "C"]

  @filename = "data-#{Time.now.to_date.to_s}.csv"  
end
send_data(csv_string, :type => 'text/csv; charset=utf-8; header=present', :filename => @filename)
```

This is in the controller **generate_data** and action **csv_cars**.

When I run this action (**webste.com/generate_data/csv_cars**), it will automatically pop up a window to download the file.

But how to write the CSV content to the action? So when I open the URL, I'll see there written the content from the database?

Comment: `render` it as text. Look [this](https://github.com/beerlington/render_csv) gem, i use it in the same case.

Comment: But should I write then something to the **csv_cars** file? Also, should I use the `send_data` construction? (Btw, thanks for the prompt reply)

Comment: send_data - [Sends the given binary data to the browser. This method is similar to render :text => data, but also allows you to specify whether the browser should display the response as a file attachment (i.e. in a download dialog) or as inline data. You may also set the content type, the apparent file name, and other things.](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_data)

Answer (score 22):

I know this is an old thread but I came across it in my search so in case someone else does the same, here's my answer and what worked for me.

I think bhanu had a good way of going about it but I did change something. Instead of doing @cars within the respond_to, I just called send_data Cars.to_csv since, as Rob stated, it was made as a class method. It worked beautifully for me.

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.to_csv(make)
    attributes = %w{id name price} #customize columns here
    cars = Car.where(maker_name: make)

    CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
      csv << attributes

      cars.each do |car|
        csv << attributes.map{ |attr| car.send(attr) }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And then in the controller

```
class CarsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    send_data Cars.to_csv('Chevy'), filename: "cars-#{Date.today}.csv"
  end
end
```

I understand that this will be called when you go to cars/index but you can put that into any method, if statement or anything you want and just have it called whenever you would like from there. You can also have arguments, as I did above with make, and query for certain fields. It was definitely a lot easier than I thought it was going to be. Hope this helped someone.

Comment: What is the option `headers: true` passed to `CSV.generate`? What is the effect of that option? I can't find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 7):

You need to do something like this.

```
def csv_cars
  headers = ['column one', 'column two', 'column three']

  csv_data = CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
    csv << headers
    csv << ["A", "B", "C"]
  end

  send_data csv_data, filename: "data-#{Date.today.to_s}.csv", disposition: :attachment
end
```

Answer (score 6):

define a to_csv method in your model as shown below

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.to_csv
    attributes = %w{id name price} #customize columns here

    CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
      csv << attributes

      all.each do |car|
        csv << attributes.map{ |attr| car.send(attr) }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Later in your controller

```
class CarsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @cars = Car.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.csv { send_data @cars.to_csv, filename: "cars-#{Date.today}.csv" }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: How can that possibly work? def self.to_csv defines a class method, @cars.to_csv is callint an instance method.

Comment: @cars represents an active record relation which responds to class methods, not instance

Comment: @bhanu How can i add this process in delay job?